# mysql_aurora ignore auto_increment value on insert

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

We are having a problem with AUTO_INCREMENT in Mysql, where it ignores the value of AUTO_INCREMENT and continues from the highest id record.

We have 2 segments of data
A- #0 - #10000
B- #10002 - unlimited

the first set is predefined data that gets loaded to the db on a specific event, thus we preserve the first range of ids (0-10000).

For the insert without id value, we use the second segment and set the table AUTO_INCREMENT to #10002 for all new tables expecting it will start counting at #10002

After applying `ALTER TABLE [TABLE_NAME] AUTO_INCREMENT = 100002` it works fine at the moment but after a few days/weeks (random time) it starts to ignore the value.

The problem is that it ignores the value and continues counting from the last row id or 1 if it's an empty table.

Any recommendations will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Aurora is not MySQL - Amazon Aurora is a MySQL and PostgreSQL **compatible** relational database management system (RDBMS)

Comment: From RDS configuration:
Engine version
8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.2

Comment: Did the instance restart or fail over since you did the ALTER TABLE?

Comment: @BillKarwin we assume it did restart because we have been applying the ALTER TABLE everyweek for the last 3 months at least. we also suspect the atuo-updates in the maintenance window. but don't know how to verify that.

Comment: You can run this query in a MySQL client connected to that instance: `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'uptime';` As far as I know it will be accurate on Aurora. The point is that InnoDB resets auto-increment on each table on restart. It will be reset to the maximum value stored in that table plus 1, regardless of what you set it to with ALTER TABLE. MySQL 8.0 fixes this by making the auto-increment value persistent, but I don't know that Aurora incorporated this change. Aurora has changed a lot of InnoDB code.